# How to Sort all country's and Languages using Multidimensional Array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, zend-framework, multidimensional-array

I am working on a project where I have to Sort all Country's and languages in ascending order and display it.

Sorting with language is very difficult, I dint find this type of problem when i goggled. I spent hours to solve this but still couldnot solve this. When i am uncommenting `sort($languages);` it shows index of the array.

I need the category (i.e Country) and the languages to be sorted in a proper way (Ascending).

Sorting in English and some languages seems to work fine. but for languages like Japanese and some other languages its not working.

And the `<th>` tag works only for the Russia Languages Categort tag. please help with the design also.

i would be very thankful to you'l if you can solve this. Thanks in advance...

Here is what i tried.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<body>
<?php 
$languages = array(
'Russia' => array(
                'Russian'=>'rʌʃə',
                ),
'Japan'=>array('Japanese'=>"日本" ,'America'=>'アメリカ'),
'India' => array(
                'Bengali' => "ગુજરાતી", 
                'Hindi'   => 'क्रिकेट',
               'Telugu'   => "తెలుగు",
               'Malyalam'   => "മലയാളം",
               'Oriya' => 'ଓଡ଼ିଆ oṛiā',
               'Kannda' => 'ಕನ್ನಡ ಲಿಪಿ',
               'Kashmiri'=>'کٔشِیر',
               'Konkani' => 'कोंकणस्थ',
               'Panjabi' => 'ਪੰਜਾਬੀ',
               'Sanskrit'=>'संस्कृत',
               'Tamil' => 'தமிழ்'

        ));
        //sort($languages);
    echo "<table border='1' ><tr><td>";
        foreach ($languages as $obj_key =>$book){
        echo "<th>$obj_key Languages Category</th>";
                echo "<table border='1'>";
                    foreach ($book as $key=>$value){
                    echo "<tr><td>$key </td><td> $value</td></tr>";
                    }
                echo "</td></tr></table>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The the problem is not yet solved by here. and I need to sort it in human language(ascending) where there are 6800 languages . without using multidimensional array. by associative array.

```
    $languages=array ('アメリカ','日本','ગુજરાતી','क्रिकेट','తెలుగు','മലയാളം','ଓଡ଼ିଆ oṛiā','ಕನ್ನಡ ಲಿಪಿ','کٔشِیر','कोंकणस्थ','ਪੰਜਾਬੀ','संस्कृत','தமிழ்');
   //sort ($languages);
   foreach ($languages as $language) {
      echo $language.'<br/>';
   }
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate what is your desired order?

Comment: Thanks Passerby for the edit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check, your html structure is not correct.

I think it should be as follows

```
    echo "<table border='1' >";
    foreach ($languages as $obj_key =>$book){
    echo "<thead><tr><th>$obj_key Languages Category</th></tr></thead>";

                foreach ($book as $key=>$value){
                    echo "<tr><td>$key - $value</td></tr>";
                }

    }
    echo "</table>";
```

I see you are using nested tables, but first check it in normal tables

**SOLUTION**

after your languages array

```
ksort($languages);
echo "<table border='1' >";
    foreach ($languages as $obj_key =>$book){
        echo "<thead>
                   <tr>
                      <th>$obj_key Languages Category</th>
                   </tr>
              </thead>";
        ksort($book );
        foreach ($book as $key=>$value){
              echo "    <tr><td>$key - $value</td></tr>" . PHP_EOL;
        }

    }
    echo "</table>";
```

this will surly work for you (http://codepad.org/dnZuvfjr) working copy here

Comment: Thanks Aamir Mohamood. The design is looks better.